# IIS URL Rewrite Module - Change Querystring Parameter Value forming multiple query string

Tags: redirect, iis, iis-7, iis-express, url-rewrite-module

```
   <rule name="replace query string" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)(ip=1)(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)(ip=1)(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}?{C:0}ip=0{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
```

I have used the above rule and its creating duplicate query string

I have used below url

http://test.com/track/?ip=1&_=1589821794782

My main goal is to update the test.com to api.com and then change ip=1 to ip=0.

Can you please help me I'm new to this?

Generated URL [http://test.com/track/?ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=0&*=1589821794782&ip=1&*=1589821794782](http://test.com/track/?ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=0&_=1589821794782&ip=1&_=1589821794782)

[image]

Comment: If you feel my answer helps you, please mark it as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is some issue in your rule pattern. you can see the below failed request tracing result of your rule:

[image]

to fulfill your retirement you could try to use below rule:

```
<rule name="replace query string" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="test.com" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="ip=1(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://api.com/{R:1}?ip=0{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: How did you check the request tracing result? Can you please let me know how to do this? @jalpa-panchal

Comment: @ShajinChandran you could refer this link how to do failed request tracing in iis for the URL rewrite module https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules